# tesseract build error in visual studio 2013

Tags: c++, ocr

I'm trying to build tesseract in visual studio 2013, but there is a problem like this. I followed the guide from http://vorba.ch/2014/tesseract-3.03-vs2013.html, but build of solution is not working. Do you know what I should do?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKKc8.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

File->Save equationdetect.cpp as-> click drop down button besides "Save" ->
select "Save with Encoding" -> click yes to overwrite -> select Chinese Simplified GB2312
Then I was able to compile with Release build for x64 target under MSVC 2015.

Answer (score -1):

it should be typo (not F7 but F6 instead) on that web tutorial guide..
BTW, original code (equationdetect.cpp):
static const STRING kCharsToEx[] = {"'", "`", "\"", "\", ",", ".","〈", "〉", "《", "》", "」", "「", ""};

replace to:
static const STRING kCharsToEx[] = { "'", "`", "\"", "\", ",", ".", "〈 ", "〉 ", "《 ", "》 ", "」 ", "「 ", "" };

then re-build can pass via VS2013.